# Exporting an auxiliar function outside the scope of a Adonis JS Controller class

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs-ace

I have an AdminController with a lot of backend API endpoints and there is an auxiliar function that one of the API depends upon. I need to call this auxiliar function from a Task File that runs every day in the morning. I tried exporting an object using module.exports = { AdminController,  createReportAux } but that did not seem to work. How can I achieve this? Am I doing the import or export wrong?

```js
class AdminController {

// backend API endpoint methods

    async deleteProgram({ request, params, response }) {
}

    async addProgram({ auth, request, response }) {
}

//I could call this but cannot pass auth information from the task file as it is not available there
    async createReport({ auth, params, response }) {
                        createReportAux(requestInfo, auth.user.email)
}

}


//function that I need to call which is outside AdminController class
const createReportAux = async (requestInfo, email) => {
}

module.exports = AdminController


const AdminController = use("App/Controllers/Http/AdminController")

class GetScheduledEmailForTheDay extends Task {
  static get schedule() {

  }
 await AdminController.createReportAux(requestInfo, individualEmailToSend.receiver_email)

}
```

Please suggest a solution, I have been stuck at it for a while. Exporting as an object seems to work but the API methods are not accessible that way.